# PHP command line blank when I type statements

Tags: php

in Windows 7 I launch PHP.exe but then there's just a pure black command prompt screen and nothing I type results in any feedback at all.  If I type:

```
PHP -I
```

Nothing.  If I type

```
PHPinfo()
```

Nothing.

Nothing beyond a blinking underscore cursor.  Everything else in the command window is black.  (Ctrl C brings me back to to a dir command prompt.)

Comment: No errors, no output, no nothing?

Comment: It's been so long since I've used this.  I went back after I posted and tried entering the statements directly into the command line and everything's fine.  I had been typing "php" and pressing return and then been trying to use the statements.  (As I said it's been a long time.)  Everything's cool now.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: You meant php -i
which is lowercase i, to get phpinfo.

Answer (score 3):

PHP was initially a HTML preprocessor, and the interprreter only executes code inside `<?php` `?>` tags; the rest is left untouched. The way you are using it now, php would just print the text `phpinfo()` back to you.

But it doesn't do so because it is waiting for *the rest* of the page to be input, and will delay execution until it reaches "end of file". On Windows this means you have to enter <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> on a line by itself.

That, *and* your input is missing the "end of statement" marker – the **`;`**.

> `<?php`
>
> `phpinfo();`
>
> <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you want to use "interactive" mode as in Python or Ruby's `irb`, you need to run **`php -a`**, which will execute every line immediately.

<s>You will *still* need `<?php`, however, and it will *still* immediately die on syntax errors, so</s> *(these were fixed in 5.4)*

I suggest you to use a text editor instead – write some code, save it to `test.php`, then run `php test.php` from command line. Edit, fix bugs, run `php test.php` again.